# Spresense SDKにてスタートアップスクリプトの設定でmake時にエラー発生

Tags: spresense

Spressense SDKを始めたばかりの初心者です。
自動起動をさせたいのですがMakeエラーが発生して設定ができません。

#### 環境

- spresenseの環境設定に沿って最新版で環境構築
- CLI、IDEどちらでも同じ症状

#### 症状

下記のコンフィグレーション設定はエラーもなく成功しますがmake時にエラーが発生します。

```
./tools/config.py examples/hello feature/startup_script
```

※「feature/startup_script」を付けなければmake時のエラーは発生しません。

#### make時のエラー

```
CC:  nsh_romfsetc.c
In file included from nsh_romfsetc.c:34:
nsh_romfsetc.c: In function 'nsh_romfsetc':
nsh_romfsetc.c:89:28: error: 'romfs_img_len' undeclared (first use in this function)
   89 |   desc.nsectors = NSECTORS(romfs_img_len);   /* The number of sectors in the RAM disk */
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
nsh.h:367:33: note: in definition of macro 'NSECTORS'
  367 | #  define NSECTORS(b)        (((b)+CONFIG_NSH_ROMFSSECTSIZE-1)/CONFIG_NSH_ROMFSSECTSIZE)
      |                                 ^
nsh_romfsetc.c:89:28: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
   89 |   desc.nsectors = NSECTORS(romfs_img_len);   /* The number of sectors in the RAM disk */
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
nsh.h:367:33: note: in definition of macro 'NSECTORS'
  367 | #  define NSECTORS(b)        (((b)+CONFIG_NSH_ROMFSSECTSIZE-1)/CONFIG_NSH_ROMFSSECTSIZE)
      |                                 ^
nsh_romfsetc.c:91:19: error: 'romfs_img' undeclared (first use in this function)
   91 |   desc.image    = romfs_img;                 /* File system image */
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~
make[4]: *** [/home/yozoi/spresense/sdk/apps/Application.mk:133: nsh_romfsetc.c.home.yozoi.spresense.sdk.apps.nshlib.o] エラー 1
make[4]: ディレクトリ '/home/yozoi/spresense/sdk/apps/nshlib' から出ます
make[3]: *** [Makefile:42: /home/yozoi/spresense/sdk/apps/nshlib_all] エラー 2
make[3]: ディレクトリ '/home/yozoi/spresense/sdk/apps' から出ます
make[2]: *** [Makefile:36: all] エラー 2
make[2]: ディレクトリ '/home/yozoi/spresense/sdk/apps' から出ます
make[1]: *** [tools/LibTargets.mk:210: /home/yozoi/spresense/sdk/apps/libapps.a] エラー 2
make[1]: ディレクトリ '/home/yozoi/spresense/nuttx' から出ます
make: *** [Makefile:114: all] エラー 2
```

Answer (score 0):

私も以下最新のSDKv2.5を利用しているので、試してみましたが、buildはできています。
https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense/releases/tag/v2.5.0

もし、gitのcheckoutなどのコマンド操作や、configを切り替えたりしていたら、余計なファイルが残っている可能性があります。一度’make distclean’をしてから、再度同じconfigを指定してmakeを試してみたらいかがでしょうか？